# tf-hub and recipes / tidymodels

Tags: r, keras, tidymodels, tensorflow-hub

I'm going through the tfhub-recipes example [here](https://github.com/rstudio/tfhub/blob/master/vignettes/examples/recipes.R). However, after running the basic example, I tried to add in hyperparamter tuning and got the error

```
internal: Error: Only strings can be converted to symbols
```

Does anyone know why that might happen when adding in a workflow and hyperparameter tuning?

```
library(tfhub)
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)
library(here)
#> here() starts at C:/Users/ChadPeltier/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpcXVvsD/reprex59f4226d175a
library(furrr)
#> Loading required package: future

comments <- read_csv("https://github.com/cgpeltier/non_defense_projects/raw/master/comments_sample.csv")
#> 
#> -- Column specification --------------------------------------------------------
#> cols(
#>   obscene = col_double(),
#>   comment_text = col_character()
#> )

comments_split <- initial_split(comments, strata = obscene)
comments_train <- training(comments_split)
comments_test <- testing(comments_split)
comments_folds <- vfold_cv(comments_train, strata = obscene)

ctrl_grid <- stacks::control_stack_grid()

rec <- recipe(obscene ~ comment_text, data = comments_train) %>% 
    step_pretrained_text_embedding(comment_text, handle = "https://tfhub.dev/google/tf2-preview/gnews-swivel-20dim-with-oov/1") %>%
    step_bin2factor(obscene) 

glmnet_spec <- logistic_reg(penalty = tune(), mixture = tune()) %>% 
    set_mode("classification") %>% 
    set_engine("glmnet") 

glmnet_workflow <- workflow() %>% 
    add_recipe(rec) %>% 
    add_model(glmnet_spec) 

glmnet_grid <- crossing(penalty = 10^seq(-6, -1, length.out = 20), 
                        mixture = c(0.05, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1)) 

n_cores <- availableCores() - 1
plan(multiprocess, workers = n_cores)

glmnet_tune <- tune_grid(glmnet_workflow, 
                         resamples = comments_folds, 
                         control = control_grid(save_pred = TRUE),
                         grid = glmnet_grid) 
#> x Fold01: internal: Error: Only strings can be converted to symbols
#> x Fold02: internal: Error: Only strings can be converted to symbols
#> x Fold03: internal: Error: Only strings can be converted to symbols
#> x Fold04: internal: Error: Only strings can be converted to symbols
#> x Fold05: internal: Error: Only strings can be converted to symbols
#> x Fold06: internal: Error: Only strings can be converted to symbols
#> x Fold07: internal: Error: Only strings can be converted to symbols
#> x Fold08: internal: Error: Only strings can be converted to symbols
#> x Fold09: internal: Error: Only strings can be converted to symbols
#> x Fold10: internal: Error: Only strings can be converted to symbols
#> Warning: All models failed. See the `.notes` column.

future:::ClusterRegistry("stop")
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Please update your question with the full error trace.

Comment: Full error messages added

Comment: I would wrap this up in a [reprex](https://www.tidyverse.org/help/) and post it as an [issue on the tfhub GitHub](https://github.com/rstudio/tfhub/issues).

Comment: Thanks Julia. I added in a reprex based on a subset of the kaggle data and posted it [here](https://github.com/rstudio/tfhub/issues/23).